# Pushing new date to ember javascript array

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am creating a basic ember app with javascript object arrays(Don't want to use anything else until I get a firm grasp).  I am having trouble 
implementing functionality to add new users. I'm not sure what to add to my controller.

In the template:

```
<form {{action 'add-student' on="submit"}}> 
{{input id="add-student" type="text" placeholder="student name"  value=name}}
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

My students route:
import Ember from 'ember';

```
 var students = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'John',

}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Vanessa'     
}];

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return students;
  }
});
```

Comment: Write the `add-student` action, most likely in the controller, and there do a `this.get('model').pushObject(something)`.

Answer (score 1):

For route you might want something like this. Using Ember.RSVP.hash it allows you to return 1-n properties from model.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    const store = this.get('store');
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        students: Ember.A([
          store.createRecord('student', { name: 'Vanessa'})
        ]),
        someOtherModelThing: store.find('xx') 
    })
  }
});
```

In the template you would want something like this.

```
{{input type="text" value=name}}

<button class="btn btn-default" {{action "addNewStudent" name}}>Add</button>
```

And to handle addNewStudent you would need to write an action in controller.

```
...

    actions: {
       addNewStudent(studentName) {
          const store = this.get('store');
          var newStudent = store.createRecord('student', {name: studentName});
          this.get('model.students').pushObject(newStudent);
       }
    }

...
```

And if you're also looking to save them you might wanna have save button with an action 'saveStudents'.

```
saveStudents: function() {
   return Ember.RSVP.all(this.get('model.students').invoke('save'))
}
```

Showing the list of students in the template.

```
{{#each model.students as |student|}}
    <p> {{student.name}}
{{/each}}
```

All of this can be achieved without using ember-data (store.createRecord etc..). using plain JSON and Ajax to save data.

Comment: What is 'store'? this.get('store');

Comment: **store** is the service that enables you standardized ways of communication with the server in case you are using **ember data**.  Please check [api documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html) and [guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/models/defining-models/) for better understanding of model, ember data, and store.